# double в char си

Tags: c, double

Пишу программу по этому заданию. `Написать функцию для преобразования переменной типа double в строку символов с заданной точностью представления ( dtoa( double num, int npos, int nfr ) ) и тестирующую программу к ней, где npos --- общее число знаков (включая запятую), а nfr --- число знаков после запятой.`
Что от меня хотят в npos и nfr? Чтобы я ввел количество символов в введенном числе или же количество символов которые выведутся в конце?

Comment: Несколько странное задание. На сколько понимаю, от Вас хотят, чтобы функция принимала параметры выходной строки: сколько в ней всего должно быть символов, и сколько - после запятой.

Answer (score 3):

Количество символов в *передаваемом* числе вы не можете указать в силу специфики его представления в памяти компьютера.

А вот при выводе - запросто. Так что ваша функция для `dtoa(M_PI, 8,5)` должна выводить  `3.14159` или `03.14159` — дополнять ли слева нулями или пробелами, это уж смотрите внимательно в полном тексте задания, как и что делать при неверных параметрах, типа, вся длина — 5 символов, а после запятой — 8...